# python, loop through json value fields error

Tags: python, json

Still new to python and playing around with a testversion of a json file, which looks unusual to me, lots of [] instead of {}.

How to print every block inside of "people" (the amount of entries varies) with a loop?
Listing all the "Name" and "Team" blocks. (even better without the first, which is kind of a description)

json:

```
{
    "summary": [
        [
            "users:",
            60
        ],
        [
            "time:",
            "0:00:12"
        ],
        [
            "Status:",
            "OK"
        ]
    ],
    "people": [
        [
            "Name",
            "Team"
        ],
        [
            "Carl",
            "Sales"
        ],
        [
            "Jane",
            "Support"
        ]
    ]
}
```

i tried:

```
from json import load
with open('test.json','r') as file:
   data = load(file)

for c in data['people']:
    print (data['people'][c][1])
```

or with

```
print (c[c][1])
```

Despite searching i fundamentally cannot understand this:
"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list"

when, for example
print(data['summary'][0][1])
gives me what i want, but putting a variable in, not.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over `people`, which is a list. So when you index using each element of the list, you are indexing a list with it's sub-lists:

```py
people = [
        [
            "Name",
            "Team"
        ],
        [
            "Carl",
            "Sales"
        ],
        [
            "Jane",
            "Support"
        ]
]

element = people[0]

print(element)

['Name', 'Team']

people[element]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 people[element]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

instead, index the resulting sub-lists:

```py
for c in data['people']:
    print(c[1])
```

Or, use tuple unpacking:

```py
for name, team in data['people']:
    print(team)
```

Comment: i still have to completely understand it, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction, that works.